# Reading PDF File Attachment Annotations with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, annotations, itext, attachment

I have the following issue. I have a PDF with a XML file attached as annotation inside it.
Not as embedded file but as annotation. Now I try to read it with the code from the following link:

[iTextSharp - how to open/read/extract a file attachment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007780/itextsharp-how-to-open-read-extract-a-file-attachment)

It works for embedded files but not for file attachemts as annotations.

I Google for extracting annotations from PDF and find out the following link:
[Reading PDF Annotations with iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474210/reading-pdf-annotations-with-itext)

So the annotation type is "File Attachment Annotations"

Could someone show a working example?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<del>As so often in questions concerning iText and iTextSharp, one should first look at the [keyword list on itextpdf.com](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keywords.php). Here you find [File attachment, extract attachments](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=490) referencing two Java samples from [iText in Action — 2nd Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book/):</del>

The old keyword list is no more; the itextpdf.com site now offers other ways for searching examples but I won't describe them lest the site changes again and I have dead links once more...

The relevant iText examples based on [iText in Action — Second Edition](https://itextpdf.com/de/resources/books/itext-action-second-edition/itext-action-second-edition) are:

- part4.chapter16.KubrickDvds

- [Java, iText 5.x](https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/I5JS/repos/book/browse/src/part4/chapter16/KubrickDvds.java)
- [Java, iText 7.x](https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/I7JS/repos/book/browse/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/samples/book/part4/chapter16/Listing_16_05_KubrickDvds.java)
- [.Net, iText 5.x](https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/I5NS/repos/book/browse/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter16/KubrickDvds.cs)

- part4.chapter16.KubrickDocumentary

- [Java, iText 5.x](https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/I5JS/repos/book/browse/src/part4/chapter16/KubrickDocumentary.java)
- [Java, iText 7.x](https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/I7JS/repos/book/browse/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/samples/book/part4/chapter16/Listing_16_06_KubrickDocumentary.java)
- [.Net, iText 5.x](https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/I5NS/repos/book/browse/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter16/KubrickDocumentary.cs)

here are [Samples from iText5](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it5kb/examples/itext-in-action-chapter-16-pdf-streams)

(I haven't found ports of the samples to .Net and iText 7 but based on the other sources this port should not be too difficult...)

KubrickDvds contains the following method `extractAttachments`/`ExtractAttachments` to extract File Attachment Annotations:

Java, iText 5.x:

```
/**
 * Extracts attachments from an existing PDF.
 * @param src   the path to the existing PDF
 */
public void extractAttachments(String src) throws IOException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfArray array;
    PdfDictionary annot;
    PdfDictionary fs;
    PdfDictionary refs;
    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        array = reader.getPageN(i).getAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
        if (array == null) continue;
        for (int j = 0; j < array.size(); j++) {
            annot = array.getAsDict(j);
            if (PdfName.FILEATTACHMENT.equals(annot.getAsName(PdfName.SUBTYPE))) {
                fs = annot.getAsDict(PdfName.FS);
                refs = fs.getAsDict(PdfName.EF);
                for (PdfName name : refs.getKeys()) {
                    FileOutputStream fos
                        = new FileOutputStream(String.format(PATH, fs.getAsString(name).toString()));
                    fos.write(PdfReader.getStreamBytes((PRStream)refs.getAsStream(name)));
                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    reader.close();
}
```

Java, iText 7.x:

```
public void extractAttachments(String src) throws IOException {
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src));
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfArray array;
    PdfDictionary annot;
    PdfDictionary fs;
    PdfDictionary refs;
    for (int i = 1; i <= pdfDoc.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        array = pdfDoc.getPage(i).getPdfObject().getAsArray(PdfName.Annots);
        if (array == null) continue;
        for (int j = 0; j < array.size(); j++) {
            annot = array.getAsDictionary(j);
            if (PdfName.FileAttachment.equals(annot.getAsName(PdfName.Subtype))) {
                fs = annot.getAsDictionary(PdfName.FS);
                refs = fs.getAsDictionary(PdfName.EF);
                for (PdfName name : refs.keySet()) {
                    FileOutputStream fos
                            = new FileOutputStream(String.format(PATH, fs.getAsString(name).toString()));
                    fos.write(refs.getAsStream(name).getBytes());
                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    reader.close();
}
```

C#, iText 5.x:

```
/**
 * Extracts attachments from an existing PDF.
 * @param src the path to the existing PDF
 * @param zip the ZipFile object to add the extracted images
 */
public void ExtractAttachments(byte[] src, ZipFile zip) {
  PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
  for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++) {
    PdfArray array = reader.GetPageN(i).GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
    if (array == null) continue;
    for (int j = 0; j < array.Size; j++) {
      PdfDictionary annot = array.GetAsDict(j);
      if (PdfName.FILEATTACHMENT.Equals(
          annot.GetAsName(PdfName.SUBTYPE)))
      {
        PdfDictionary fs = annot.GetAsDict(PdfName.FS);
        PdfDictionary refs = fs.GetAsDict(PdfName.EF);
        foreach (PdfName name in refs.Keys) {
          zip.AddEntry(
            fs.GetAsString(name).ToString(), 
            PdfReader.GetStreamBytes((PRStream)refs.GetAsStream(name))
          );
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

KubrickDocumentary contains the following method `extractDocLevelAttachments`/`ExtractDocLevelAttachments` to extract document level attachments:

Java, iText 5.x:

```
/**
 * Extracts document level attachments
 * @param filename     a file from which document level attachments will be extracted
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void extractDocLevelAttachments(String filename) throws IOException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filename);
    PdfDictionary root = reader.getCatalog();
    PdfDictionary documentnames = root.getAsDict(PdfName.NAMES);
    PdfDictionary embeddedfiles = documentnames.getAsDict(PdfName.EMBEDDEDFILES);
    PdfArray filespecs = embeddedfiles.getAsArray(PdfName.NAMES);
    PdfDictionary filespec;
    PdfDictionary refs;
    FileOutputStream fos;
    PRStream stream;
    for (int i = 0; i < filespecs.size(); ) {
      filespecs.getAsString(i++);
      filespec = filespecs.getAsDict(i++);
      refs = filespec.getAsDict(PdfName.EF);
      for (PdfName key : refs.getKeys()) {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(String.format(PATH, filespec.getAsString(key).toString()));
        stream = (PRStream) PdfReader.getPdfObject(refs.getAsIndirectObject(key));
        fos.write(PdfReader.getStreamBytes(stream));
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
      }
    }
    reader.close();
}
```

Java, iText 7.x

```
public void extractDocLevelAttachments(String src) throws IOException {
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src));
    PdfDictionary root = pdfDoc.getCatalog().getPdfObject();
    PdfDictionary documentnames = root.getAsDictionary(PdfName.Names);
    PdfDictionary embeddedfiles = documentnames.getAsDictionary(PdfName.EmbeddedFiles);
    PdfArray filespecs = embeddedfiles.getAsArray(PdfName.Names);
    PdfDictionary filespec;
    PdfDictionary refs;
    FileOutputStream fos;
    PdfStream stream;
    for (int i = 0; i < filespecs.size(); ) {
        filespecs.getAsString(i++);
        filespec = filespecs.getAsDictionary(i++);
        refs = filespec.getAsDictionary(PdfName.EF);
        for (PdfName key : refs.keySet()) {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(String.format(PATH, filespec.getAsString(key).toString()));
            stream = refs.getAsStream(key);
            fos.write(stream.getBytes());
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        }
    }
    pdfDoc.close();
}
```

C#, iText 5.x:

```
/**
 * Extracts document level attachments
 * @param PDF from which document level attachments will be extracted
 * @param zip the ZipFile object to add the extracted images
 */
public void ExtractDocLevelAttachments(byte[] pdf, ZipFile zip) {
  PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
  PdfDictionary root = reader.Catalog;
  PdfDictionary documentnames = root.GetAsDict(PdfName.NAMES);
  PdfDictionary embeddedfiles = 
      documentnames.GetAsDict(PdfName.EMBEDDEDFILES);
  PdfArray filespecs = embeddedfiles.GetAsArray(PdfName.NAMES);
  for (int i = 0; i < filespecs.Size; ) {
    filespecs.GetAsString(i++);
    PdfDictionary filespec = filespecs.GetAsDict(i++);
    PdfDictionary refs = filespec.GetAsDict(PdfName.EF);
    foreach (PdfName key in refs.Keys) {
      PRStream stream = (PRStream) PdfReader.GetPdfObject(
        refs.GetAsIndirectObject(key)
      );
      zip.AddEntry(
        filespec.GetAsString(key).ToString(), 
        PdfReader.GetStreamBytes(stream)
      );
    }
  }
}
```

(For some reason the c# examples put the extracted files in some ZIP file while the Java versions put them into the file system... oh well...)

Comment: OK. Thank you. It works perfectly. The function ExtractAttachments is what I need.

Comment: is there any version for iText7 ?

Comment: @Bernhard Ports to iText 7.x for Java exist; I've updated my answer here.

Comment: @mkl - you're genius!

Comment: what a shame the examples at itext are no longer avail...
but, thanks to archive.org :)

Comment: the book can be found here : https://github.com/zxh/iText/raw/master/iText%20in%20Action%202nd%20Edition.pdf