# IText Shows less pages than there actually are

Tags: pdf-generation, itext

I have code that takes a bunch of PDFs and combines them into one file...

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos)
....
PdfFileSpecification fs = PdfFileSpecification.fileEmbedded(writer, null, af.fileName, af.documentData.data)
fs.addCollectionItem(item)
writer.addFileAttachment(fs)
```

This works great and I see all of the pages as I would expect. Now I am looking to split it up  and copy to multiple sub files based on size. However, when I consume the generated byte[] iText only seems to see the first page...

```
 PdfCopy copy = null
 PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(before) // Add the byte array here
 int pages = reader.getNumberOfPages() //It is only 1 I would expect more pages.
```

It seems to only be recognizing the cover page which was added before the other documents. Is there a way I can get the count of ALL pages? If I take before and just send it as an attachment it shows up with all 1xx pages.

Comment: Are you trying to split up the already "combined" PDFs or are you trying to re-architect your "combing" logic?

Comment: You are *combining* the files by attaching them to a new PDF which only has a cover page and making this file a *Portfolio* as Adobe calls it. If you want to access the pages of these attached PDFs, you have to extract them again and open them in separate `PdfReader` instances.

Comment: @mkl is right and should turn his comment into an answer. His answer should be accepted.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie *turn his comment into an answer* - Ok, there you are! ;)

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted today's answer and the answer you refer to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are combining the files by attaching them to a new PDF which only has a cover page, and making this file a Portfolio as Adobe calls it:

```
PdfFileSpecification fs = PdfFileSpecification.fileEmbedded(writer, null, af.fileName, af.documentData.data);
fs.addCollectionItem(item);
writer.addFileAttachment(fs);
```

Thus, your code is not one of the typical merge functions (using `PdfCopy` or `PdfWriter` with `getImportedPage`; correct ones use `PdfCopy`, fishy ones use `PdfWriter`) which generate a single PDF containing all source pages as genuine document pages. Instead your code creates a single page document with other PDFs as attachments and some extra information making PDF viewers display the attached PDFs inline.

**If you want to access the pages of these attached PDFs, you have to extract them again and open them in separate `PdfReader` instances.**

You can find more information on extracting PDF attachments in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14951567/1729265).