# Extracting the embedded attachments in PDF

Tags: java, itext

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PRStream;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfArray;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDictionary;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfName;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfString;

public class extractAttachments{

public extractAttachments(String src, String dir) throws IOException {

    File folder = new File(dir);
       folder.mkdirs();
       PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
       PdfDictionary root = reader.getCatalog();
       PdfDictionary names = root.getAsDict(PdfName.NAMES);
       PdfDictionary embedded = names.getAsDict(PdfName.EMBEDDEDFILES);
       PdfArray filespecs = embedded.getAsArray(PdfName.NAMES);
       for (int i = 0; i < filespecs.size(); ) {
         extractAttachment(reader, folder, filespecs.getAsString(i++),
         filespecs.getAsDict(i++));
       }
     }

    protected void extractAttachment(PdfReader reader, File dir, PdfString name, PdfDictionary filespec)
       throws IOException {
       PRStream stream;
       FileOutputStream fos;
       String filename;
       PdfDictionary refs = filespec.getAsDict(PdfName.EF);
       for (PdfName key : refs.getKeys()) {
         stream = (PRStream)PdfReader.getPdfObject(refs.getAsIndirectObject(key));
         filename = filespec.getAsString(key).toString();
         fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(dir, filename));
         fos.write(PdfReader.getStreamBytes(stream));
         fos.flush();
         fos.close();
       }
     }
  }
```

I have tried the above code for extracting the embedded attachment from the PDF.but it is not working for the PDF that is having wordDocument. I am using itext5.It is working for the PDF having text document.  What can be the issue?

Comment: The accepted answer of [Reading PDF File Attachment Annotations with iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14947829/1729265) has code both for C# and for Java.

Comment: Strange: my comment was removed. Why? It wasn't rude, was it?.It referred to a possible duplicate question and it asked if the OP knew the difference between document-level annotations and page-level file annotations. I'm getting fed up with moderators removing comments of a 50K+ Stack Overflow users. I might move away from Stack Overflow altogether if these censoring actions continue.